# Predicting the primary keys exhaustion in MySQL based on rate of insertion

Tags: mysql, primary-key, information-schema, limits

We are running out of primary keys for our table in production. We do not want that to occur again. So we need a mechanism to alert us when we are running out of primary keys based on the rate of insertion so that we can mitigate that.

I have written a Jenkins job that executes a query on `information_schema` and extracts the `index_length`, `table_rows` and `auto_increment` from the MySQL database. But we need to keep track of the previous reading since we want to take `diff` of it with the current in order to predict when the keys are going to be exhausted.

```
SELECT 
  INDEX_LENGTH, TABLE_NAME, AUTO_INCREMENT, TABLE_ROWS 
FROM 
  information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY 
  index_length DESC;
```

I cannot find anything related to the rate of change in MySQL tables that should predict the rate at which the primary keys are being used up. I am also open to use any good alternate approach if anyone thinks of but keep in mind I have to get a query run by a cron job or Jenkins job that should tell that which tables will be exhausted at the end of this year.

Comment: Seems like `index_length` is far too crude to trust.  `table_rows` is only an estimate for InnoDB.

Comment: Why not use bigint for all primary keys and don't worry about "burning" values?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find tables that have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.
2. Discover the datatype of that column, including `SIGNED` vs `UNSIGNED`.
3. Use that to establish the drop-dead limit.
4. `SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl;` to see where you are now.

At that point, you can go one of two directions.

Plan A:  Compute what percent of the limit the id already is, and sort on that.

Plan B:  Check `MAX(id)` a week later, then compute how many weeks before the limit will be hit.

When you do find a table that is threatening to hit the limit, find out if the ids are being "burned".  Do this by comparing `COUNT(*)` versus `MAX(id)`.  Either the table is really big (compared to the datatype used), or there are a lot of gaps.

If there are a lot of gaps, then dig into what the code does.  There are many flavors of `INSERT` that "burn" ids.  `REPLACE` burns a id because it is effectively `DELETE` + `INSERT`.  `INSERT IGNORE`, if the row is present, burns the id that it otherwise would use.  IODKU burns when it updates.  Etc.

If you are burning ids due to Normalization, see [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table#normalization).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than delete records or re-assign primary keys you could use the datatype of bigint assuming it is currently int. This will stop you running out but I am led to believe this may affect performance.
Do you have a test environment to test query speeds?

Comment: yeah, we are moving to bigint for some tables, but for the rest of the databases, we want to have alert mechanism to alert us like for example a year before we run out of the primary keys. pt online schema is used to migrate all the records to a new table with the changed datatype. Simply we just want to know beforehand we are ruuning out of primary keys based on the rate of insertion

Comment: @ali If the tables you're inserting into have an associated date_added, date_inserted, etc. column, you could do a query with a count and group by on the date added to find the rate of insertion. If they don't have a column like that, you would likely need to create an additional table to store the date that each column is added so you will have something to query, or add a date_added column.

Comment: Using a bigger datatype for ids will only slightly hurt performance.  Don't worry about it for typical usage.  (If you have a terabyte of data, then it becomes important.)